# SSH Stopped working

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, ssh, configuration, restart

I restarted my computer, and now I can't connect to it through ssh on my remote machine. I can connect to it through the host machine, but that's it. It says ssh is running, but I can't connect from another computer.

Comment: What happens when you try to ssh in from the remote computer?

Comment: Using putty it says: "Searching for host..." Then it says "Network error: Connection to myip has timed out"

Comment: Also my terminology might be a little off seeing that i am kind of new to this. By remote do you mean the computer i am trying to connect to. Or the computer i am connecting from?

Comment: Does your network use DHCP for assigning IP addresses, and are you trying to connect using an IP address, as in `ssh user@192.168.1.5`? If so, rebooting the computer may have resulted in the IP address changing. You can get the IP address of the host through Network Manager on the host computer or through `ifconfig` in Terminal.

Comment: My ip adress is static so that could not have happened. I am connecting using ssh user@192.168.0.90. Im also pretty sure that my network uses DCHP. Also, thanks for the quick response :)

Comment: Make sure you don't have a VPN running on either PC. I had this problem when running a local network.

Answer (score 3):

Things to check on the remote machine (the machine you are connecting to):

- ssh server is running (which you've already done): `sudo service ssh status`
- firewall isn't interfering: `sudo iptables -L` to check firewall rules
- basic connectivity: `ping 192.168.0.90` (should get a response)
- physical network issues (cable out, switch down, etc.)
- both computers are on the same subnet (192.168.0.). If you've reset the router, it could be granting IP addresses on a different subnet than your SSH server's static one.

Comment: All of it was clear... It worked, but i still cant connect via another computer.

Comment: do you have denyhosts installed? Denyhosts is a really nice program that blocks IP addresses that have N failed authentication attempts. See http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/faq.html#3_19 if that's the case.

Comment: I have never installed anything like that.

Comment: I would check anyway, it may have been pulled in by another package. Another thing to check is the /etc/ssh/sshd_config. There are options that would limit what addresses and ports that SSH listens to. Seems unlikely that would be changed, though.

Comment: would you like me to post the config?

Comment: That might help. Can you also think of what you you might have changed on the system since this worked last?

Comment: Here is the sshd config http://pastebin.com/9QCdZLcX0 Here is the ssh config http://pastebin.com/pMP8qHgA I did change the ip to a static one, but it has since been changed back due to this problem. Also before i reinstalled ssh, i had put SessionAliveInterval 60 into the ssh config. I dont think that it is there anymore though.

Comment: first link says it's been removed.

Comment: Have you ruled out a problem with putty by using another Terminal client??

Answer (score 0):

Check the firewall in the remote machine:

```
iptables -nvL
```

or:

```
systemctl status firewalld
```